# Return JSON to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use AJAX to call a script php this script will return text in format JSON when i put dataType:'json' my code don't work but when i put dataType:'html' it's work
there is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            dataType : 'json',
            url : 'ws_stb_status.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {stbInfo:stbInfo},
            success : function(data){
                    $("#StbStatus").html(data);
                    $("#wait").html('');
            }
    });
```

script.php:

```
$rpi ="http://192.168.1.15";
if (isset($_POST['stbInfo']))
 {  

if($_POST['stbInfo']=="On")
{

    $url=$rpi.'/StbGetDataModel.php';
    $response = proxy::get($url);
    $url=$rpi.'/upload/datamodel.txt';
    $response = preg_split("/[\r\n\t\f]+/",proxy::get($url));
    $text = '';
    $model = '';
    foreach($response as $pair){
        $res=explode('=',$pair);
        switch($res[0]){
            case 'DeviceInfo.AdditionalSoftwareVersion':
                $text = $text.'Version Loader,Firmware,AR : '.$res[1].'<br />';
                break;
            case 'DeviceInfo.Manufacturer':
                $text = $text.'Fabriquant : '.$res[1].'<br />';
                break;
            case 'DeviceInfo.ModelName':
                $text = $text.'Mod&#232;le : '.$res[1].'<br />';
                $model = $res[1];
                break;
        }
    }
    $arr['model'] = $model;
    $arr['text'] = $text;
    echo (json_encode($arr));
}
```

}

Thank you in advance

Comment: `$("#StbStatus").html(data);` with `dataType` set to `'json'` wouldn't work. The returned *json* is an `object`, not an HTML string. Something like (to access `model`) `$("#StbStatus").html(data.model);` should work. Ditto for `$("#StbStatus").html(data.text);` And in your `foreach > switch > case 'DeviceInfo.ModelName'` you're overwriting `$model` on each iteration of the loop. Is that by design?

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's work

Comment: I've added it as an answer if you wouldn't mind *accepting* it, so that future visitors to the site can see what ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap into ob_start/clean:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// .. logic here
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

By any reason, you probably sending some extra data.

You can also force a header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Edited to include `die()` -- this prevents any more of the script executing and possibly outputting to your json response

Answer (score 0):

To access the *returned* JSON `Object` properties (`model` and `text`) you need to use the following:

```
$("#StbStatus").html(data.model); // data.model now holds the model response

$("#StbStatus").html(data.text); // data.text now holds the text response
```